# In order to keep using ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION on background, should I use ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION as well?

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to keep counting step on background so I use Foreground Service.

When I test this with devices, I feel like android version less than 13 has stopped after a couple of days.

So I search on this and found the document that in order to use `Body Sensor` from version 13, it needs to give `BODY_SENSORS_BACKGROUND` permission.

[image]

Now I use `ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION` permission, not `BODY_SENSOR`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
```

So I thought this is not my case.

But at the same time, I just wonder I need to give permission regarding background work as well on manifest for ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION.

So I ask question on chatgpt,
`ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION should also give BACKGROUND permission in manifest?`

Then I get answer from gpt:

> Yes, if your app needs to continuously monitor the user's activity
> even when it's running in the background, you'll need to request the
> ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION permission along with the
> android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission in your app's
> manifest file.
>
> Starting from Android 10 (API level 29), apps must obtain both
> permissions to be able to access the activity recognition data in the
> background. This is because access to this data can reveal sensitive
> information about the user's daily routine and location, and Google
> wants to ensure that user privacy is protected.
>
> Here's an example of how to request these permissions in your app's
> manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

Is this right? SO should I also give permission for `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` as well ?